# How to select the row with the max column from another subquery in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlplus, oracle19c

Basically I'm trying to find the max of a count outcome. Here's an example:

**Desired output:**  the name of the employees with the highest number of jobs and the number of jobs done.

My tables (bold means primary key, * means foreign key):

- Employees (**Id**, employee_name,....)
- Sites (**Site_id**, Site_name,....)
- Jobs (*Site_id**, *Id**, DateJ)

Here are 2 things I tried:

Query #1:

```sql
Select 
    employee_name, 
    max(jobs_done) max_jobs
from 
    Employees E,
    (select 
         id, 
         count(*) jobs_done from jobs
     from jobs
     group by id) t
where 
    E.id = t.Id
group by 
    employee_name;
```

This returns the max jobs of each employee which is pointless as the subquery already does that, and it's not the desired outcome.

Query #2:

```sql
Select 
    employee_name,
    t.job_done
from
    Employees E
    (Select 
         id, 
         count(*) job_done
     from Jobs
     group by id) t
where 
    E.id = t.id
order by 
    jobs_done desc
fetch first row only;
```

This kinda works in my situation, but doesn't account to multiple employees having the same max.

is there a simple way to solve this, obviously without changing the DB layout and preferably using only subqueries (I'm still a beginner)?

Comment: Maybe you need [`with ties`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html) instead of `only`?

Comment: @astentx That does in fact work. I'll keep the post up for if someone else wants to contribute more. thanks you!

Comment: Can the same employee_name have different IDs?

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov Yes they can, since ID is the primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, looks like you need to aggregate by `Employee.ID`, instead of `Employee_name`, since jobs are linked by ID, not `employee_name`. So it's better to push aggregating and Top-N into the subquery to `Jobs`. Though Oracle has a special query transformation mechanism `Group-By Pushdown` (and even a special hint `gby_pushdown`), it's better to make own queries clearer and more predictable and do not rely on CBO (Oracle Optimizer) magic.
Secondly, I would suggest to use ANSI join syntax at least for beginners, since it's a bit more clear.

So it should look like this:

```
Select 
    e.id,
    e.employee_name,
    j.jobs_done
from
    (Select 
         id, 
         count(*) jobs_done
     from Jobs
     group by id
     order by jobs_done desc
     fetch first 1 row with ties
    ) j
    join Employees e
        on e.id = j.id
;
```

As you can see `j` subquery aggregates jobs by `employee.id` and gets only top 1 `with ties`, then we just join `Employee` to get `Employee_name`